# Filter last word after matching a string

Tags: text-processing, grep

I need to filter out some hexadecimal value from a return string of a command in bash for example:

```
hexVal=`mmc extcsd read /dev/mmcblk1 | grep 'Max Enhanced Area Size'`
```

Will return the value of hexVal as:

```
Max Enhanced Are Size [MAX_ENH_SIZE_MULT]: 0x000bd8
```

Now, I need the value of hexVal to be returned as:

```
0x000bd8
```

Comment: Yes @jimmij. They are the last words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `grep`, you could use `awk` as it is more useful in pattern matching and printing out the matched fields

```
mmc extcsd read /dev/mmcblk1 | awk -F: '$1 ~ "^""Max Enhanced Area Size" { print $2 }'
```

You could also remove the leading space in the above result

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ "^""Max Enhanced Area Size" { sub(/^[[:space:]]/,"",$2); print $2 }'
```

If you are to use `grep` and have the GNU version of it installed, use the PCRE mode

```
grep -oP '^Max Enhanced Area Size.*:(\s+)\K(.+)'
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Inian. The grep command you suggested works perfectly